# Properly setting primary/secondary and fees payer

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using PayPal's adaptive API to make chained payments.  I need to split a single payment from a user between one or more (up to the maximum of 9) other users.  I'd like to also allocate a portion of the payment to myself equal to PayPal's fees plus our own, and specify that I pay the fees.  During my approval process, I was told that the user needed to be the primary receiver and we had to be secondary.  But this seems odd if I have have more than one user payee, for a couple of reasons:

1. I'd have to arbitrarily pick one of the user payees to be primary.
2. If I am just one of several secondary payees, then there's no feesPayer value I could use to indicate that I'm paying the fees.

What's recommended under this scenario?

Comment: First, Adaptive Payments will only accept up to 6 receivers, so you'll need to consider that with your development.  Second, did you respond back to PayPal when they told you this with the application?  They can often work with you if there are legitimate reasons for what you're doing, which it sounds like there is.  I know I've done similar apps that you're doing and they were approved no problem, but I'm a PayPal Partner, so that could have something to do with it.  ;)

Comment: I've seen the 6-maximum in some PayPal documentation, but I saw the 9 number under the Chained Payments section here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/  Do you know which is the real number?

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe they expanded it to 9 and haven't updated the other docs yet.  I guess you'll just have to test it in the sandbox.